# Android - force network requests go through wifi instead of mobile network

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi

I have an app which connects to a hardware device Wi-Fi hotspot.
It seems that Android forward requests over other networks (3G/4G for example) instead the hotspot, since my hot spot has no internet connection.

Is there any way to force network stream to work on the wifi?
I've come across the following function, but it's deprecated:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#setNetworkPreference(int)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [Connecting your App to a Wi-Fi Device blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/07/connecting-your-app-to-wi-fi-device.html):

> To direct all the network requests from your app to an external Wi-Fi device, call [ConnectivityManager#setProcessDefaultNetwork](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#setProcessDefaultNetwork(android.net.Network)) on Lollipop devices, and on Marshmallow call [ConnectivityManager#bindProcessToNetwork](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)) instead, which is a direct API replacement.

Comment: Thanks. seems like the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ConnectivityManager to get the state of the Wifi adapter and then you can check if it is connected or even available using NetworkInfo.

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (wifi.isConnected()) {
    // Continue with logic
}
```

In case he is not connected to wifi then don't proceed else continue you flow.

Add the following permission in you Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```