# Ignore Captive Portal and use WIFI as is

Tags: android, android-wifi

We have a service that displays a user captive portal when a users IP address changes on their WIFI. We are building an app which automates the login. The issue is while android is in a state of 'Wifi requires signin' any network activity is done through the cell connection and the wifi is not accessible.

So when we ping a script on our server to determine the users new IP address it returns the cell network IP. How can we utilize the WIFI connection that is available and still have it make a request? I see the option when trying to sign in manually to 'use the network as is', but need to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

OK so the solution we found was the following which enables us to use the WIFI to ping a script of ours.

To direct all the network requests from your app to an external Wi-Fi device, call [ConnectivityManager#setProcessDefaultNetwork](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#setProcessDefaultNetwork(android.net.Network)) on Lollipop devices, and on Marshmallow call [ConnectivityManager#bindProcessToNetwork](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)) instead, which is a direct API replacement.

as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39312069/1736785)