# nativescript force wifi in http request

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

as the title says, is there a way (with Nativescript) to force the app to use the wifi connection for an http request? i am connected need wifi to a raspberry configured as hotspot without internet connection....my problem is when the smartphone is connected to the mobile data, it try to communicate with the datas due the fact that on wifi there isn't connection i suppose. if i disable mobile data it works because the unique connection is wifi. so is there a way to force the http request on wifi connection?
sorry for my english, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var connectivity = require("connectivity");
switch (connectivity.getConnectionType()) {
case connectivity.connectionType.wifi:
    //http request or what do you want... 
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

more info about connectivity , check [this](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/connectivity)

Comment: i yet use this, but in absence of connectivity over the wifi it tries always to communicate with the mobile data

Comment: did you call request func in switch-case? Your request function can only by wifi connection on this way. You can add a timer to try again after 15 sec if you request is fail

Comment: hello, unfortunately i could try only on saturday or on sunday, i will let you know. thank you

Comment: @peppeg85 what s result?

Comment: yes, it works, i use it once on the main page and it communicate over wifi each httprequest, i used it wrongly, with if(connectivityModule.connectionType.wifi)..thank you

Comment: hello, i have this problem again, with the updates of nativescript, the code is the same of the NS page: https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/connectivity#basics, but the switch seems to return the connection with internet navigation, i need to use the wifi also if there is no internet over it

Comment: if there is no internet on wifi, device may pass to mobile network automatically. If I don't remember wrong; there is an option to force to pass mobile data when wifi internet interrupted. So use "connectionToString(Connectivity.getConnectionType()" and log to console periodically. You can check is there any connection-switch event automatically (by android or iOS).

Comment: yes, it' my case, i need to force the wifi connection both for android and ios, but i can't find an answer with nativescript, only the connectivity utils, but it checks the internet connection...any idea?

Comment: You can not force to use Wi-Fi, only OS user can do it(android and ios). You can just pop up or warn to user in an app. For example when you catch an interrupt on Wi-Fi or different connection from Wi-Fi; then alert a message to screen as "pls pass to Wi-Fi!... some description for user etc.etc.". Just lt. Or somethings like that.. If you find any fix about forcing Wi-Fi , pls write here to know everybody

Comment: hi, i found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311853/android-force-network-requests-go-through-wifi-instead-of-mobile-network, is there a way to use it with nativescript?

Comment: in fact, I have no idea about it(especially on iOS) :/